# Java generics, nesting Type parameters

Tags: java, generics

I want to create a generic method that gets a `Collection<T>` as parameter, does something on the elements (mapping) and returns a `Collection<R>`.
This isn't a problem, with the following declaration:

```
public <R,T> Collection<R> foo(Collection<T> c);
```

Now, I want to force my method to return a Collection of the same type of the parameter, so there will be no need to cast the return value to the specific collection. Something like this:

```
public <R, T, S extends Collection> S<R> foo(S<T> c);
```

Sadly enough, this doesn't compile.

Can this be done somehow? What is the right way to do this?

Comment: You cannot parameterize type parameter token. You might probably want: `..., S extends Collection<T>` and then `(S c)`.

Comment: What relationship is R to T?

Comment: @Powerlord, i want to apply a Mapper of type T->R. There is no relation between T and R.

Comment: @orimarcovitch How do you intend to create a new instance of the Collection?

Comment: @k5_ `collection.getClass().getConstructor().newInstance()`

Comment: @orimarcovitch not all Collections will provide that constructor. Commonly used ones would be Arrays.asList() or stuff returned by Collections.synchronized* or Collections.unmodifieable*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this if you want to use generics is to do the following:

```
public <R, S, CR extends Collection<R>, CS extends Collection<S>> CR foo(CS c);
```

The issue is binding your argument and your return to a type.

Comment: I want to force the collections to be of the same type, so Java will infer the return value and I won't need to cast it every time  I call the method

Comment: @orimarcovitch Did you actually try the code? No casting needed.

Comment: Although I still don't understand how Java infers the return type. Must be some type erasure magic...

Answer (score 0):

You can not tie two generics together that way. Anyway even if you can you still would need to create a new collection in foo. (You can not reuse c, that would create a poluted heap)

One way of doing it would provide a supplier for the collection that enforces the type:

```
  public static void callFoo(){
     List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
     ArrayList<Integer> foo = foo(strings, ArrayList::new);
  }

  public static <R,T, S extends Collection<R>> S foo(Collection<T> ts, Supplier<S> supplier){
    S s = supplier.get();
    for(T t:ts){
        s.add(null);
    }
    return s;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Method Overloading in Java, try to overload your data manipulation in your mapping method.

Comment: I didn't really understand your solution, but anyway, overloading isn't going to cause my return value to be as I want...